# Spark driver stopped unexpectedly (Databricks)

Tags: apache-spark, driver, azure-databricks

I have a Python notebook in Azure Databricks which performs a for loop with 137 iterations. For each iteration, it calls another Scala notebook using `dbutils.notebook.run`. The Scala notebook creates a DataFrame from a query to a MongoDB database. I create a global temporary view in the Scala notebook using `df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView("<<view_name>>")` because I need to recover this data from the Python notebook and keep processing it. The code to read from the Python notebook looks like this:

```py
global_temporary_database = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.globalTempDatabase")
for _ in range(137):
    dbutils.notebook.run(path="<<path_to_scala_notebook>>", timeout_seconds=600, arguments=<<current_configuration>>)
    # Recover the data and drop the global temporary view
    df = table(f"{global_temporary_database}.<<view_name>>")
    spark.catalog.dropGlobalTempView("<<view_name>>")
    # Do some processing like filtering rows and rename columns
```

This works for a limited number of iterations. However, when I try to run the whole loop I get the following error:

```
The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached
```

I've tried to use `time.sleep()` to add some delay between iterations to avoid overloading the cluster. I've also tried to use `spark.catalog.clearCache()` after each iteration but it doesn't work.

Below are the cluster specs:

- Databricks Runtime Version: 9.1 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.1.2, Scala 2.12)
- 2 Workers: 61 GB Memory, 8 Cores
- 1 Driver: 16 GB Memory, 4 Cores

Unfortunately, I need to use 2 notebooks because I'm using a Scala library to apply some operations to the DataFrames, and then I need to share this data between notebooks, so there's no way to avoid that part.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by calling my Scala notebook only once and moving all the loop logic into the Scala notebook, which was a bit tedious. But I guess it's not a good idea to call a notebook 137 times as it produces a lot of overhead.

The execution time has improved significantly. Now it takes around 20 minutes, whereas previously it took 1 hour to eventually stop the driver and not finish.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in my environment while replicating the issue:

[image]

I removed  `spark.stop()`  from the code and run the code it again. It run successfully without any error:

[image]

For more information you can check below page:

[https://kb.databricks.com/jobs/driver-unavailable#:~:text=One%20common%20cause%20for%20this,to%20frequent%20full%20garbage%20collection](https://kb.databricks.com/jobs/driver-unavailable#:%7E:text=One%20common%20cause%20for%20this,to%20frequent%20full%20garbage%20collection).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I wasn't using spark.stop() in the first place. I've posted my own solution but your help is appreciated :)